# MediaStore not returning results when querying public Download folder (Android Q)

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mediastore, scoped-storage

I am trying to download a (apk) file to the "Download" folder on the root of the sdcard in a Android project targeting Android Q (API 29) using Xamarin.

First I download the file to the private storage space of the app located at sdcard/Android/data/com.my.app/files

Then I use the MediaStore API to copy the file to the public "Download" folder. This is my code:

```
private void SaveTest(string appPath, string fileName)
    {
        var contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.Put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DisplayName, fileName);
        contentValues.Put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MimeType, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        contentValues.Put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RelativePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);

        var context = (Context)this;
        var resolver = context.ContentResolver;

        Stream stream = null;
        Android.Net.Uri uri = null;

        try
        {
            var contentUri = MediaStore.Downloads.ExternalContentUri;

            var cursor = resolver.Query(
                contentUri,
                new[] { MediaStore.MediaColumns.Id, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DisplayName, MediaStore.MediaColumns.MimeType, MediaStore.MediaColumns.RelativePath },
                $"{MediaStore.MediaColumns.DisplayName} = ? AND {MediaStore.MediaColumns.MimeType} = ? AND {MediaStore.MediaColumns.RelativePath} = ?",
                new[] { fileName, "application/vnd.android.package-archive", Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads },
                null
                );
            if(cursor != null && cursor.Count >= 1)
            {
                cursor.MoveToFirst();

                var id = cursor.GetLong(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.Id));
                var displayName = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DisplayName));
                var relativePath = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MimeType));
                var lastModifiedDate = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RelativePath));

                uri = ContentUris.WithAppendedId(contentUri, id);
            }
            else
            {
                uri = resolver.Insert(contentUri, contentValues);
            }
            cursor?.Close();

            if (uri == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Retrieving of creating MediaStore record failed.");
            }

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            stream = resolver.OpenOutputStream(uri);

            var fullPathAndFileName = Path.Combine(appPath, fileName);
            using (var inputstream = new FileStream(fullPathAndFileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                CopyFile(inputstream, stream);
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            if (uri != null)
            {
                // Don't leave an orphan entry in the MediaStore
                resolver.Delete(uri, null, null);
            }

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            stream?.Close();
        }
    }
```

The insert in the MediaStore works the first time, but when I try to insert a second time the returned Uri is null. Therefore I added the ContentResolver query so I can detect existing records, but this query returns no results. It only ever works again when I use a different fileName.

When I take a look at the Device Log, I can see the following error:

> Time  Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
>   05-14 14:14:27.442  Error   14571   SQLiteDatabase  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: files._data (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:879)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:790)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:88)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1599)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1468)
>       at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insertFile(MediaProvider.java:2776)
>       at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insertInternal(MediaProvider.java:3317)
>       at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insert(MediaProvider.java:2966)
>       at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:309)
>       at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:154)
>       at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
>       at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
>   05-14 14:14:27.442  Error   14571   SQLiteDatabase  Error inserting bucket_display_name=Download owner_package_name=com.my.app parent=8 volume_name=external_primary date_modified=1589458467 _display_name=XXX.apk mime_type=application/vnd.android.package-archive _data=/storage/emulated/0/Download/XXX.apk title=XXX.apk group_id=102105 is_download=true date_added=1589458467 primary_directory=Download bucket_id=540528482 media_type=0 relative_path=Download/

Even when executing the mediastore query without any filters, the result count is 0. How can I obtain the correct Uri?

Comment: You add a timestamp as prefix of fileName to make sure the filename is different each time .

Comment: I figured out that the problem appears when you uninstall the app and leave the file on the sdcard. When you then try to download the file XXX.apk to the same folder, it will result in the mentioned problem. You can "fix" the problem by clearing the data of the "Mediastore" app, which will in fact clear the mediastore database. It is probably related to the fact that the app loses the read/write rights over the file when the app is uninstalled.